# "The judge is god" or "The god is judge"?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-order, sentence-patterns

In a scene in *The great debaters*, Denzel Washington's character asks his students to reiterate some lines. He asks:

> Who is the judge?

And the students reply:

> The judge is god.

Now, why is the answer not "the god is judge" instead?

I think the former one is not appropriate because "The judge is god" means in a general sense that each judge is god, doesn't it? And this was not being asked anyway. The question was asked in more specific way and "the god is judge" means that god is the judge, emphatically god is the only judge but the former answer is not emphasizing that.

Am I correct? Or are these two equal with not even the slightest of differences? If they are different, then how?

Comment: If anything, your options should be "the judge is god" and "god is the judge". "The god is judge" is a complete non-starter. Anyway, you are inconsistent in your reasoning, as the exact same ambiguity applies to the question as well, but you only ever consider the answer. Lastly, there is no point in taking the sentence out of context to discuss its ambiguity, as the ambiguity is *created* by taking it out of context in the first place.

Comment: Who the hell is the downvoter? What is your problem ?

Comment: @RegDwighт I understand your point and the answer down here clarifies my doubts, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The judge is god* means what the judge says is the law and you may not question that. He/she makes the ultimate decision in the courtroom.

To be god is to be very good or in this case decide everything

You can be a football god.

Jimi Hendrix was/is considered a guitar god

*(The) (G)god is/will be the judge* means something else entirely, that whatever god they are talking about (e.g. not God if lower case) will judge (later) - that is a religious statement but your suggestion *the god is judge* does not sound correct

Comment: +1 Could not thank you enough , that Jimi Hendrix example was an eye-opener .:)